# How to find out where Django is querying from?

Tags: django, django-models

I am relatively new to Django and web development in general. I am working on a project with my company (small company, three developers here currently who all have little to no experience) which has very little documentation, and the person who used to work on it is gone. I am getting errors when building the project, and part of the problem I think is that I may have incorrect data for building the project.

My specific question is, when you call something like Model.objects.get(), how can you tell where the program is "getting" this information from? My project has a ton of moving parts - an sqlite db, a csv spreadsheet, a whole directory of audio recording sessions, and is making use of all of them. I am not sure whether this get() is looking at any of these, or possibly an API that no one currently in my company even knows exists. Is there a standard file in most Django projects where I could see what Model.objects.get() looks at when fetching the data?

Comment: This is from django's ORM and it queries the database configured in the `settings.py` file. Based on the database type, you might be looking at local sqlite, postgresql, ... or remote databases. From the context, I think you're using sqlite locally.

Comment: Is there a certain variable name I should be looking for in settings.py? It does have the local sqlite file there, but it has a lot of other variables set as well. 

Also, the local sqlite db has a number of tables and I do not know which one I should be looking at (this is also not documented anywhere and a lot of the tables are similar (slightly different column names, contents, etc)). Is there somewhere in the program where I could print out the table name being used/find if it is hardcoded somewhere?

Comment: DATABASES object. For the second question, please dig into your project and look for `models.py` files or folders to find your models. Each model is a database table, E.g, when you use `Account.objects.get()`, you are querying the Account table in your database. There is no explicit explanation for django's projects unless documented by developers. I'm afraid you must study this project by following it's models and urls and views